# 4 balls and a balance scale

Tags: logical-deduction, weighing

What's the least amount of weighings you'd need to be able to successfully determine the weights of 4 balls weighing 1, 2, 3 and 4 kilograms, using a balance scale (counting the worst scenario)?

Any amount of balls can be placed on a single side of the scale.

Comment: Looking at the 2 answers here so far, can we please have a clarification:  Are we able to put more than one ball on each side of the scale?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A simple / basic answer, to provide an Upper Bound, is to use the scales

> 4 times

First, label our unknown balls "A", "B", "C", and "D".  Next

> Weigh them in pairs, and write down the winning pairs:
>  A&B v C&D
>  A&C v B&D
>  A&D v B&C

If, for demonstrative purposes, we assume that A=1, B=2, C=3 and D=4, then you would get this table:

> 1&2 = 3 v 3&4 = 7
>  1&3 = 4 v 2&4 = 6
>  1&4 = 5 v 2&3 = 5 : If we get the other 2 first, then we can skip this one!

We can then tally up each ball by "Heavy" versus "Light"

> 1: Light / Light / Draw
>  2: Heavy / Light / Draw
>  3: Heavy / Light / Draw
>  4: Heavy / Heavy / Draw

This means that our final step is

> Compare the 2 balls with 1 "Heavy" and 1 "Light", to work out which is 2 and which is 3

Comment: With the update I have deleted my answer as it is no longer correct. This seems to be the optimal stratergy with the rules now being clarified :)

Comment: @BeastlyGerbil It's a pity that [puzzling.se] isn't suitable for having a "sandbox" like [Worldbuilding.se] does to spot those queries slightly earlier ^_^'  And, I certainly can't find a way to knock a number off at the moment

Comment: There is no approach that guarantees success in fewer tests.  Simple brute force on the three possible non-trivial first tests shows this.